# ¿Cómo evito perder la información de un puntero (c++) al guardar una estructura de datos en un fichero?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy trabajando en un programa que almacene una cantidad indefinida de palabras y establezca ciertas relaciones entre ellas, p.ej relaciones de sinónimos, antónimos, formas verbales etc. Cada palabra es un struct con su string y un vector con sus Relaciones. Para no andar moviendo palabras de un lado para otro, guardo las relaciones con la siguiente estructura:

```
struct Relacion{
 int tipoDeRelacion; // cada numero corresponde a una relacion distinta
 *Palabra p; // la palabra con la que esta relacionada
}
```

El caso es que para guardar la información del la relación en un fichero, no puedo guardar el puntero por motivos que creo que no hace falta explicar. Otra opción es guardar el string de la palabra p en lugar de su puntero, pero precisamente quiero evitarlo por ahorrar el coste computacional. Por último se me había ocurrido asociar un código a cada Palabra, y guardar ese código en lugar del puntero o el string. El único problema que veo es el proceso de carga del fichero, porque para volver recuperar cada *Palabra p de cada Relación tendría que hacer un número enorme de búsquedas.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás lo más recomendable es que le asignes un código a cada palabra. El código podría ser un simple entero incremental:

```
struct Palabra
{
  int codigo;
  std::string palabra;
};

// Cada vez que se llama te retorna un codigo nuevo
int NuevoCodigo() 
{
  static int codigo = 1;
  return codigo++;
}
```

De esta forma almacenar las relaciones es tan sencillo como guardar el tipo de relación y el código asociado a cada palabra.

Por cierto, te recomendaría encapsular las relaciones dentro de un `enum` en vez de usar un entero. Tener un tipado fuerte mejora la legibilidad del código y evita errores tontos:

```
enum class TipoRelacion
{
  // ...
};

struct Relacion{
 TipoRelacion tipoDeRelacion; // cada numero corresponde a una relacion distinta
 *Palabra p; // la palabra con la que esta relacionada
};
```

Ahora bien si lo que te interesa es acelerar las búsquedas lo que deberías hacer es mapear el código en vez de la palabra:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::string> listaPalabras;

struct Relacion{
 int tipoDeRelacion; // cada numero corresponde a una relacion distinta
 int codigoPalabra; // <<---
};
```

O, si prefieres seguir usando memoria dinámica:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr<Palabra>> listaPalabras;

struct Relacion{
 int tipoDeRelacion; // cada numero corresponde a una relacion distinta
 std::reference_wrapper<Palabra> p;
};
```

La gracia de usar `std::unique_ptr` y `std::reference_wrapper` es que te evita lidiar con los punteros.

**Nota final:** Este código requiere C++11 para compilar, lo cual no debería ser un problema en la inmensa mayoría de los casos ya que se trata de un estándar que lleva entre nosotros 6 años ya.